# Unable to block comment a small piece of javascript code with regex

Tags: javascript, block-comments

This is the line which works perfectly fine.

```
'some words'.split(/,*/);
```

But when I do a block comment as show below, I get a syntax error.

```
/* 'some words'.split(/,*/); */
```

Couldn't find about this behaviour anywhere.
Not sure if this is a know bug in the language.

Answer (score 0):

The `*/` in your regex gets parsed as the end of the comment, which is causing the syntax error.

Can you use a single-line comment instead?

```
// 'some words'.split(/,*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in the language, the `*/` is a known (and deliberate) overlap between regular expression literals and block comment delimiters in the grammar.

You can either use a single-line comment

```
// 'some words'.split(/,*/);
```

or change your regex

```
/* 'some words'.split(/,{0,}/);
'some words'.split(/,*(?:)/); */
```